# ngx-datatable cellClass as function in templateRef

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I try to implement my css-classes to ngx-datatable cells
like shown in the demos: https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#css

I'm using TemplateRef (instead of inline-Templates in the demo)

```js
  @ViewChild('Bestand_HdrTpl') Bestand_HdrTpl: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('Bestand_Tpl') Bestand_Tpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  setColumns() {
    const dieColmn = [

      {
        cellTemplate: this.Bestand_HdrTpl,
        headerTemplate: this.Bestand_Tpl,
        prop: 'Bestand',
        name: 'LAGER_Bestand',
        canAutoResize: false,
        width: 65,
        cellClass: 'ist-bestand'
      },
      ...
      ,
      {
        cellTemplate: this.Lager_Tpl,
        headerTemplate: this.Lager_HdrTpl,
        prop: 'Lager',
        name: 'ID'
      }
    ];

    return dieColmn;
```

How do I implement the cellClass-property to call my function?

```js
getCellClass({ row, column, value }): any {

    return {

      // css-class    true oder false
      'ist-bestand': value > 0
    };

  }
```

I tried:

```js
      {
        ...

        width: 65,
        cellClass: 'getCellClass'
      },
```

```js
      {
        ...

        width: 65,
        cellClass: "'getCellClass"'
      },
```

Is it even possible with TemplateRef?

Comment: I changed all to Online-Templates...

Comment: You can do it like this:
`{
        cellTemplate: this.Bestand_HdrTpl,
        headerTemplate: this.Bestand_Tpl,
        prop: 'Bestand',
        name: 'LAGER_Bestand',
        canAutoResize: false,
        width: 65,
        cellClass: this.getCellClass
      }
`

`    getCellClass({ row, column, value }): any {
 return  value > 0  ?  " ist-bestand"  :  '' ;
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way to add css-classes to a TemplateRef.

For practical reasons I changed all to Online-Templates.